# display mysql table with a field as the main header

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a mysql data table that I am displaying on a php page. It works but I would like them be grouped under the departments they belong to. Also to remove all other field headers such as Name,Phone Email.

I tried using SORT BY but nothing happened.

eg. This is how I would like it to look like

```
                              Vehicle Department 
                    Bob        3234234     bob@acas.com
                    Hanna      3434323     Hanna@asas.com
                              Workshop Department
                    Andrew     45454523    andrew@aasdasd.com
```

This is how it currently looks:

```
ID    Name       Phone       Email               Department
1     Bob        3234234     bob@asasdas.com     Vehicle Department
2     Hanna      3434323     hanna@asasdas.com   Workshop Department
```

my current code:

```
<?php

    $db_host = 'localhost';
    $db_user = 'root';
    $db_pwd = '*****';

    $database = 'list';
    $table = 'users';

    if (!mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd))
        die("Can't connect to database");

    if (!mysql_select_db($database))
        die("Can't select database");

    // sending query
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table}");
    if (!$result) {
        die("Query to show fields from table failed");
    }

    $fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);

    echo "<table border='1'><tr>";
    // printing table headers
    for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
    {
        $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
        echo "<td>{$field->name}</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
    // printing table rows
    $temp = "";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
        echo "<tr>";

        if ($row['department'] != $temp){
        echo "<td colspan=\"3\">" . $row['department'] . "</td></tr>\n<tr>";
        $temp = $row['department'];
    }

    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['phone'] . "</td><td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";

    echo "</tr>\n";
    // $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
    // of $row to $cell variable
    foreach($row as $cell)
        echo "<td>$cell</td>";

    echo "</tr>\n";
    }
    mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

Comment: I warmly recommend switching to [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) as the old `mysql_*`-extension is deprecated and removed in newer versions of PHP.

Comment: Thank you I will change it. Just want to get it working before i fiddle :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use

```
"SELECT name, phone, email, department FROM {$table} ORDER BY department"
```

as your query, it will return only your desired columns, ordered by the `department` column.
Then you can arrange them in your table depending on their department.

Note that you might have to adjust the column names.

Try this code:

```
<?php
    $db_host = 'localhost';
    $db_user = 'root';
    $db_pwd = '*****';

    $database = 'list';
    $table = 'users';

    $conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd) or die("Connecting to database failed");

    mysqli_select_db($conn, $database) or die("Can't select database");

    // sending query
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT name, phone, email, department FROM {$table} ORDER BY department");
    if (!$result) {
        die("Query to show fields from table failed");
    }

    echo "<table border='1'><tr>";

    // printing table rows
    $temp = "";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<tr>";

        if ($row['department'] != $temp){
            echo "<td colspan=\"3\" align=\"center\">" . $row['department'] . "</td></tr>\n<tr>";
            $temp = $row['department'];
        }

        echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['phone'] . "</td><td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";

        echo "</tr>\n";
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    echo "</table>"
?>
```

Comment: this does arrange them but the department has to be the header. If you see my question above. The department must be used as the header for the data

Comment: @J.Hof that's what I meant by _you can arrange them in your table depending on their department_. But I will have another look at it.

Comment: @J.Hof I edited my answer. Please test the code provided.

Comment: not working sir this is the output: https://postimg.org/image/alpxnrkjd/

Comment: @J.Hof It works for me, I updated the answer with the complete code I used.

Comment: You sir are a Master! Thank you so much!

Comment: One small thing i would like to ask there is a small open gap next to each department heading. Any idea why that is sir? eg. |-------Admin----   |

Comment: @J.Hof Can you provide a screenshot? It doesn't do that for me. Did you change anything in the code other than your password?

Comment: never mind sir i fixed it. I added another column to the echo so i had to increase colspan to 4 ^^

Comment: @J.Hof Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to process the data to arrange in a structure you want for it.

```
<?php

$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pwd = '*****';

$database = 'list';
$table = 'users';

if (!mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd))
    die("Can't connect to database");

if (!mysql_select_db($database))
    die("Can't select database");

// sending query
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table}");
if (!$result) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}

$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);

echo "<table border='1'><tr>";
// printing table headers
for ($i = 0; $i < $fields_num; $i++) {
    $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
    echo "<td>{$field->name}</td>";
}
echo "</tr>\n";

//variable to store rearranged results;
$resultsModified = [];

// printing table rows
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    if (!isset($resultsModified[$result['department']]))
        $resultsModified[$result['department']] = [];

    $resultsModified[$result['department']][] = $row;
}

foreach ($resultsModified as $daptName => $results) {
    echo "<caption> $daptName </caption>";
    foreach ($results as $row) {
        echo "<tr>";

// $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
// of $row to $cell variable
        foreach ($row as $cell)
            echo "<td>$cell</td>";

        echo "</tr>\n";
    }
}

mysql_free_result($result);
```

However I have not tested it but this should work.

Comment: You do not have to put the exact code anywhere. Its just an example of implementation. You have to use the logic inside your foreach.

Comment: Thank you sir the table is showing but it hasnt changed at all. Still looks the same

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your output so I can have a better understanding.

Comment: if you scroll up and see how I would like the table and compare it to the screenshot you should understand what im looking for sir

Comment: This is because you are using table structure and its difficult to enter text between table rows. So you can use multiple tables in the process.

Comment: How would i do that sir? I don't have to use table structure if it would resolve the problem. I just need to get this working sir.